# changing li class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having trouble changing the class for a li using javascript.

html

```
<ul id="mainmenu" style="width:130px">
<li class="mainmenudrop"><a href="" class="drop">Contact us </a>
</li></ul>
```

css

```
#mainmenu {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: block;
}

#mainmenu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 999;
    display: hidden;
}
```

**This is the class I want to change:**

```
#mainmenu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #fffff;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    display: hidden;
}
```

**rest of css**

```
#mainmenu li a {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

#mainmenu li:hover a {
    color: #333333;
}
#mainmenu li .drop {
    padding: 1px 20px 2px 4px;
    background: url("../images/arrow2.gif") no-repeat right 4px ;
}

#mainmenu li:hover .drop {
    background: url("../images/arrow.gif") no-repeat right 4px; 
 }
```

**js (wanting to use)**

```
$(#mainmenu li:hover).click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('menuhoverswap');
    $(this).addClass('menuhoverswap');
});
```

**id to swap**

```
#menuhoverswap {
border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Normally would be ok doing it but cant get my head around it as I have done the css for the menu in a different markup, referring css to mainmenu then li rather then giving the li a class of its own.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `selector` is, or are you expecting us to tell you?

Comment: sorry not sure how to address the li that i want to change #mainmenu li:hover in the script. the class i swap it with will be called "menuhoverswap"

Comment: if you are having a link for a tag it will not work coz on click of li a tag will be triggered

Comment: If you want to target the LI, just do `$('#mainmenu li')`, but as noted by Vitorino above, the anchors will reload the page, even when the href is an empty string. To avoid it, at least stick a `#` in the href.

Comment: ok, so dont worry about the hover state? as when the mouse is moved out i would want it to return to normal.

Comment: will i have to do a mouseleave function to put back th original css?

Comment: just wondering why you want to change the id, and not just manipulate classes. also e.preventDefault() stops the link from firing the href

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing what you are trying to achieve, but here is what i think you want to try.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccx9o55s/2

```
$(".mainmenudrop").on("mouseenter", function(e){
    $(this).addClass("menuhoverswap");
});

$(".mainmenudrop").on("mouseleave", function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("menuhoverswap");
});
```

Comment: normal = border: 1px dotted #ccc,,, hover = border:1px dotted #aaa,,, onclick = border:1px solid #aaa,,,, onmouseleave = back to normal class.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Do you want to add the class on hover only?

```
$('.drop').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }, function() {
    $('.drop').removeClass('selected');
  });
```

Here the full working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3xop75Q06UW7uFeBMNhM?p=preview) with your code.

Comment: yes but on mouseleave the state should go back to the original id. not sure if i can target .drop as using this statement to pull the menu down '  $('a.drop').click(function(e) {
         $(this).next("div").slideToggle(200,'easeOutCirc');
         console.log('div clicked');
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     });
    $('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children("div").hide('medium');
    }); '

Comment: its also not swapping the class rather adding one

Comment: normal = border: 1px dotted #ccc,,, hover = border:1px dotted #aaa,,, onclick = border:1px solid #aaa,,,, onmouseleave = back to normal class.